# What could be causing intermittent flush issues?

Tags: toilet

I have looked at several similar questions, but I'm unable to determine the cause of this problem. Basically, when the toilet is flushing fine, after the flush, the level of water in the bowl is very, very low. When we flush and after flushing, see the water level in the bowl is close to the mark where it would normally be, we know we are going to have a problem with flushing. When it's flushed the next time, the water rises right to the top and does not go down. HERE IS THE WEIRD THING- The way we are able to get it to go down, is to run a large amount of water down the kitchen sink. We fill a bucket, dump it down the sink, and then let the water keep running. In a few minutes, we hear a gurgle and the toilet has returned to the "normal" low water level. Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: This could be a venting issue. Do you know if the sink and toilet are on the same stack?

Comment: The gurgling sounds exactly like a venting issue.

Comment: If this is a venting issue, (and both responses seem to think it is), what causes this, and how would I resolve it? It's mostly an annoyance, but it's happening more and more frequently, so I'd like to get it fixed once and for all.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for taking the time to answer my question. It's greatly appreciated!